# Como coletar tweets através da API Streaming, restringindo um local geográfico?

Tags: java, twitter-api

Eu gostaria de coletar tweets através de determinada palavra chave em tempo real, entretanto gostaria de tweets somente postados no brasil, pois ao fazer a coleta a api me retorna tweets do mundo inteiro. Estou utilizando a biblioteca twitter4j. No código abaixo estou coletando todos os tweets referente as palavras chave "carro".

```
package ToCollect;
import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.StallWarning;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connect.join();
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("X");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("X");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("X");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("X");


        /*
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());  
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();  

        try {
            twitter.updateStatus("It's Free!");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        */
        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                User user = status.getUser();

                // gets Username
                String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
                System.out.println(username);
                String profileLocation = user.getLocation();
                System.out.println(profileLocation);
                long tweetId = status.getUser().getId(); 
                System.out.println(tweetId);
                String content = status.getText();
                System.out.println(content +"\n");
                if (content.contains("RT @") == false)
                Connect.insere(username, tweetId, content=Replace.trata(content));

            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

       String keywords[] = {"chuteira da nike"};
       fq.track(keywords);

        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.filter(fq);  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Streaming API aceita o parâmetro [`language`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#language), que pode ser atribuído com "pt" ou "pt-BR". Na biblioteca *twitter4j* ele está presente na classe [FilterQuery](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/FilterQuery.html#language), então você tem que alterar seu código para:

```
String keywords[] = {"chuteira da nike"};
fq.track(keywords);

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
twitterStream.language("pt-BR");
```

Não recomendo utilizar o parâmetro [`locations`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations) pois além dele depender de tweets geolocalizados, que não são tão frequentes, ele não restringe o casamento das keywords que você passa no parâmetro `track`, ou seja, tweets que possuem a palavra "carro" e que não estão dentro da location box que você passou, também serão retornados. E Isso não acontece com o parâmetro `language`.

Comment: Humm, entendo, muito obrigado Luis Cipriani! Abraços